# without change the order of setTimeout, how we can get below output?

Tags: javascript

Current Output is:1 3 2,

Expected Output is: 1 2 3

Conditions are: Don't use setTimeout again and can not change the order of the console log. Pl help.

```js
console.log(1);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(2)
})
console.log(3);
```

Comment: That is the correct output, you should read about Javascript event loops. setTimeout will always run after the event stack is finished, meaning, it will always run last.

Comment: So why bother with `setTimeout()` if you don't actually want it to be delayed? What are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: `Don't use setTimeout again` well then dont use it? what do you try to solve?

Comment: @OussamaEssamadi I know It is giving the correct output but the expected output is 1 2 3 and we can modify the code by remembering both two condition.
Actually, one interviewer asked me this so I am also confused about this, how we can achieve this output 1 2 3 by this code and with both conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways - with and without `await`, but both involving a Promise.

#### With `await`

```js
async function foo() {
  console.log(1);
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(2);
      resolve();
    }, 10)
  });
  console.log(3);
}

foo();
```

#### Without `await` (using `.then`)

```js
console.log(1);
new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(2);
    resolve();
  }, 10)
}).then(() => {
  console.log(3);
});
```